# TSQL - Changing databases dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm in a new company, and trying to write a proc that loops through the databases and looks up a keyword in all the tables, procs, etc.

It works great in theory, however I've noticed that the database never changes.

I've outputted the SQL, and ran it, no problem. But if I run the piece of code, it doesn't change.

I've also played around with the code and hard-coded the table name and gotten it to work, so could it be a security feature?

Here's the TSQL:

```
Declare @Dbname varchar(250);   --Stores Database Name<br>
Declare @SearchTerm varchar(250); --What we're searching the DB for<br>
Declare @vSQL varchar(550)=''; --Variable that will hold our dynamic queries<br>
set @SearchTerm='LoadID';     <br>

select name 
from   sys.databases 
where  owner_sid != 0x01;

print @Dbname;
set @vSQL = 'use [' + @dbname + ']';
exec (@vSQL);

--exec @vSQL;
--execute (@vSQL);
--execute @vSQL);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EXEC runs in its own context. Put entire script into @vSql kind of

```
set @vSQL = 'use [' + @dbname + '];' +'--do what you need ' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something I have that does this, and a bit more is the following proc. Should loop through all DB's on a given instance, look for a keyword in the definition of objects in those dbs, as well as if any jobs make use of those objects and their last execute duration.

```
USE [master]
GO

Create Proc dbo.DependencyCheck @SearchKey Varchar(150) As

Begin

--DB Refs

Drop Table If Exists #Databases

Create Table #Databases

(
    DatabaseName Varchar(50) Primary Key
    ,Checked Int Default 0 Not Null
    ,SearchKey Varchar(150)
    ,DependencyText As 'Insert Into #Dependencies 
                                            Select Distinct ' 

                                            + '''' + DatabaseName + '''' +  
                                            ',
                                            D.id As ObjectID,
                                            O.name As ObjectName,
                                            xtype As ObjectType,
                                            S.name As SchemaName

                                            From '

                                            + DatabaseName + '.dbo.syscomments D

                                            Inner Join ' + DatabaseName + '.dbo.sysobjects O
                                                On O.ID = D.id

                                            Inner Join ' + DatabaseName + '.sys.schemas As S
                                                On s.schema_id = O.uid

                                            Where D.text Like ''%' + SearchKey + '%'''
)


Insert Into #Databases (DatabaseName, SearchKey)

    Select 

    Name, @SearchKey

    From sys.sysdatabases As S 

    Where S.filename Not Like '%.SS' --Not DB Snapshots

Declare @TargetDatabase Varchar(25) = (Select Top 1 DatabaseName From #Databases As D Where D.Checked = 0)

--Dependency Table

Drop Table If Exists #Dependencies

Create Table #Dependencies

(
    DatabaseName Varchar(50) Not Null,
    ObjectID Int Not Null,
    ObjectName Varchar(150) Not Null,
    ObjectType Varchar(15) Not Null,
    SchamaName Varchar(150) Not null
)

--Dynamic SQL for Insert
Declare @DynamicDependency Varchar(8000) = (Select D.DependencyText From #Databases As D Where D.DatabaseName = @TargetDatabase)

While @TargetDatabase Is Not Null

    Begin 

        Exec(@DynamicDependency)

        Update D Set Checked = 1 From #Databases D Where DatabaseName = @TargetDatabase

        Set @TargetDatabase = (Select Top 1 DatabaseName From #Databases As D Where D.Checked = 0)
        Set @DynamicDependency = (Select D.DependencyText From #Databases As D Where D.DatabaseName = @TargetDatabase)

    End

;With JobStats As
(
Select Distinct

J.name,
JH.step_id,
First_Value(JH.run_duration) Over (Partition By J.name, JH.step_id Order By CA.StartTime Desc) As Last_Duration,
Avg(JH.run_duration) Over (Partition By J.name, JH.step_id) As Avg_Duration

From msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory As JH

Cross Apply (Select Convert(Datetime, Convert(varchar(8),run_date))
 + Convert(datetime, Stuff(STUFF(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 6) +  CAST(run_time as varchar(6)), 6), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':')) As StartTime) CA  

 Inner Join msdb.dbo.sysjobs As J
    On J.job_id = JH.job_id

Where JH.step_id <> 0
And JH.run_status = 1 -- Success 
)

Select 

D.ObjectID
,D.DatabaseName
,D.SchamaName
,D.ObjectName
,D.ObjectType
,J.name As JobName
,JS.step_id As JoBStepID
,JS.step_name As JobStepName 
,JStat.Last_Duration
,JStat.Avg_Duration

From #Dependencies As D 

Left Join msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps JS
    On JS.command Like '%' + D.ObjectName + '%'
    And JS.subsystem = 'TSQL'
Left Join msdb.dbo.sysjobs J
    On J.job_id = JS.job_id

Left Join JobStats JStat
    On JStat.name = J.name
    And JStat.step_id = JS.step_id

Order By 1, 3

End
```